# Doesn't recognized obb file while run my corona application on android device

Tags: android, debugging, sdk, coronasdk, apk-expansion-files

I'm building a game for mobile devices with corona sdk, it already run on iOS devices and now I want to install it on android device.

I'm trying to install my app on android device and because my app is large than 50mb, the corona split it into apk and obb files.

apk = 12mb,
 obb = 130mb

I copied the both of files into my device and put the obb file under "sdcard/Android/obb/myPackagefolder" folder (according to some guides),
then I launch and install the apk.

now - when i'm trying to open my application it open the download page to try download the data (obb file) from google play and doesn't recognize the file I already put into the obb's folder.

I tried to run it on another devices and I get the same issue.

my build.settings contains the permission  "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

my Q: is it even possible to do that ? and what I miss that cause my problem?

please help me, I spend a lot of time on it..
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I address the file like this directly under the SD card and it wirks fine:

```
local fileName = "/sdcard/coordinates1.txt"
local doc_path = system.pathForFile( fileName )
local contents = doc_path:read( "*a" )
```

start with something like this and then use other folders.